# Maven app-assembler, assembly and classpath: config directory conflict

Tags: eclipse, maven, appassembler

I am using app-assembler Maven plug-in to create an installation of my Java application. I want some of the data (properties and some user-produced data) to be available in the filesystem rather than in any Jar file.

app-assembler allows me to do just that by adding a `config` directory to classpath.

The contents of that same `config` directory are needed to run some of my tests. Therefore, I declare that directory a resource in my Maven configuration.

Here is where the disconnect happens: if I set the targetPath of my config directory resource to "config", it's very easy for assembly (not app-assembler) plug-in to pick it up for packaging, but the classpath URL will be different between deployed application and Eclipse: the deployed app will think the URL is `classpath:/default.properties`, while inside Eclipse the URL is `classpath:/config/default.properties`. If I make the targetPath to be empty (installed directly under `classes`, the classpath URLs match between Eclipse and deployed environment, but there is no nice way to pick out the config data in teh assembly plugin configuration.

At the moment I am going with the second option, and place into `config` directory everything from `classes` that is not a class.

A better solution may be to create another classpath directory in Maven, similar to `classes` and `test-classes`, but I am not sure how to do that.

So I have two questions:

- am I  missing something obvious in resource, assembly and app-assembler plugins?
- or if I am not, then how can I add `config` directory to classpath in Maven/Eclipse environment the same way it's added by app-assembler scripts in deployed environment?

Versions used: Maven3, app-assembler 1.2.2,

Comment: Which version of appassembler-maven-plugin do you use? Have you taken a look into the generated script (appassembler-maven-plugin)? Can you post the pom?

Comment: Answered in the edit to question about versions. I'd rather not post the pom. And the scripts do exactly what they are supposed to do: form a classpath consisting of all Jars and config directory. I could use env vars to add to that classpath.